# How to write a regular expression with substitution of arguments?

Tags: javascript

How to write a regular expression with substitution of arguments?

```js
const string = 'Hello! test test: %d{1} test %w{1,2} test %w' 

const result = string.split(/%[d|w]/g).flatMap((item) => [item, '<div>test</div>']).slice(0, -1)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: What should the result be? How are the placeholders to be evauated - what's `%d` or `%w` and how are the numbers after them used?